# Ayuda al generar tabla para captura informacion wn c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mvc

La problemática que presento es la siguiente.

1.- en un View tengo que capturar campos para dos modelos, entonce lo que hago es lo siguiente.

en el actionresult de index, para poder generar el modelo ocupo lo siguiente.

```
var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ViewBag.MtoCompaniaId = new SelectList(ComboHelper.GetCompanias(0), "MtoCompaniaId", "Nombre");
        ViewBag.MtoTipoCompraId = new SelectList(ComboHelper.GetTipoCompra(0), "MtoTipoCompraId", "Descripcion");
        ViewBag.MtoTipoEventoId = new SelectList(ComboHelper.GetTipoEvento(0), "MtoTipoEventoId", "Descripcion");
        ViewBag.MtoTipoMercadoId = new SelectList(ComboHelper.GetTipoMercado(0), "MtoTipoMercadoId", "Descripcion");


        ViewBag.Tareas = ComboHelper.GetTareasAll();

        var Procedimiento = new MtoProcedimiento
        {
            MtoUsuarioId = user.MtoUsuarioId,
            MtoCompaniaId = user.MtoCompaniaId,
            MtoEstadoId = ComboHelper.GetStatus("Activo", db),              
        };

        return View(Procedimiento);
```

hasta ahi  ningun problema; el problema es cuando recupero los datos del  **ViewBag.Tareas** en la view lo cual lo hago de la siguiente manera.

```
@{
List<WebDBT.Models.MtoTarea> tareas = ViewBag.Tareas;
}
```

ahora bien genero una tabla para poder capturar la información de las tares de la siguiente manera.

```
<div class="table-title">                           
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Descripción de la Tarea</th>
                                    <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
                                    <th>Fecha Fin</th>                                        
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            @foreach (var item in tareas)
                            { 
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)</td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="datepicker" /><td>
                                    <td class="col-md-2">@Html.TextBox("FechaFin",null, new { @class = "datepicker"})</td>                                       
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </table>                            

                    </div>
```

bien me genera la tabla, pero si se dan cuenta en los campos que intento generar de las 2 manera html & @html; en ambos casos les pongo la clase **"datepicker"** ; sin embargo para los 2 últimos registro  de ambos casos no muestra el datapicker que debería mostrar.

el script es el siguiente.

```
<script>
    //=======================================
    //DESCRIPCION:PARAMETRIZACION PAR CAMPOS DE TIPO FECHA
    //FECHA : Marzo 22, 2018
    //=======================================
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(
            {
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',                   
            });

    });
</script>
```

podrian ayudarme o confirmar si, estoy haciendo bien para poder generar la tabla y que respete la clase.

gracias.

Comment: Comprobaste que se añade en el html ese datapicker? Luego el script lo metería dentro de un $( document ).ready()

Comment: si ya lo probé de hecho en los primero 3 campos si muestra el datepicker, el problema son los 2 último campos que se generan con el for